# Poisson distribution problem - traffic problem

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, queueing

Hi So I have this question below. I know I need to model each lane as a separate Poisson distribution. The possible answers are:

a) **11.4%; 22.4%; 33.4%; 44.4%; 55.4%**

b) **2.74%; 4.74%; 12.74%; 34.74%; 64.74%**

but obviously I need to know how to get to the answer.

> Question:
>
> Vehicles arrive at a rate of $1200$ vehicles per hour at a traffic
>   signal. $15\%$ of the vehicles turn right while $85\%$ travel straight
>   through. The street has one lane per direction, which is widened at
>   the intersection to one straight through lane, and one right-turn
>   lane. The right-turn lane can accommodate $5$ vehicles but will be
>   blocked if $5$ or more straight-through vehicles are waiting at the
>   intersection. Determine the following:
>
> a) The probability that no vehicles are waiting in the right-turn lane
>   while there is a total of $5$ vehicles waiting at the intersection.
>
> b)The probability that more than $5$ right-turn vehicles will arrive at
>   the intersection during the next red period of $45$ seconds.

For question **a)** I think I need to find $\Pr(X=5)$ for the straight lane while $\Pr(X=0)$ for the right lane. 
$$
\Large P_P(x; qt) = \frac{(q\cdot t)^x\cdot e^{-q\cdot t}}{x!}
$$

Where I am having trouble though is how do I determine $q$?

Comment: Can you provide the reference for the text?

Comment: Unfortunately the source is from a question my lecturer gave in a previous year's assignment. The question was a multiple choice type question. with the answers: a) 11.4%; (22.4%); 33.4%; 44.4%; 55.4%
b) 2.74%; 4.74%; 12.74%; (34.74%); 64.74%

Comment: Can we assume that the red-light cycle of 45 sec. applies to question a?

Comment: @AntoniParellada See answer below. I think I have it. Obviously the "answers" I showed in the question were incorrect. Furthermore, the 45sec must be used in a), surely?

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to answer homework problems, but one indirect way of looking into part (b) of the problem is to simulate (the closed-form solution still up to you). It seems as though your question elicited quite a bit of interest, and it could possibly get more entries if you erased the actual answers. So here it goes...

In R:

```
set.seed(0)
lambda_right = 0.15 * 45 * 1200/60^2        # Rate parameter of 2.25 cars/period (45 sec.)
nsim = 10^6                                 # One million simulations
right_arrivals = rpois(nsim, lambda_right)  # Poisson process rate lambda
mean(right_arrivals > 5)                    # Percentage with more than 5 R turning cars
[1] 0.027423
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

The mean value is clearly consistent with the setup on the simulation ($\lambda =2.25$), and it is clear that the majority of arrivals are below $5$ cars/period, explaining the low percentage for $>5$.

Answer (score 0):

Take 2:

a)Conditional probability of 5 cars going straight, given that there are 5 cars already.

[image]

=44.37%

==========================================================================

b)

[image]

=2.74%
Can anyone confirm my answers?

Comment: Part (a) is asking for a *conditional* probability. Given that there are five vehicles waiting in total, what's the probability that none of them are in the right-turn lane, as opposed to one in the right-turn lane & four in the straight-through lane, or all five in the right-turn lane? (You don't need to make any assumptions about the cycle time of the signal.)

Comment: @AntoniParellada: You're welcome! But don't you think you're giving away too much too soon in your answer? With regard to (b): there are only 3 seconds on average between cars - can a Poisson process be a sensible model for arrivals?

Comment: @Scortchi thanks for the help. I think i understand what you mean. See my second attempt. Can you confirm my answers now?

Comment: Furthermore, I should have mentioned that the question was supposed to be answered as either Binomial or Poisson. I used Poisson due to the time relation... Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @Kyle: Your assumptions need stating & justifying. You seem to have assumed two independent Poisson distributions & calculated the conditional probability from their joint distribution & the marginal distribution of the total. (The LHS notation looks the wrong way round by the way.) Though that's a reasonable approach, you could in fact get the same result from weaker assumptions.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: Well 28% of cars would be just a second behind the one in front, which starts to sound dangerous. Even at high speed a non-negligible proportion would be on top of each other.  Considering just the cars turning right, it's not so bad, of course; but a student might reasonably take a different tack & assume a constant flow of traffic with right-turners randomly interspersed (or grub for bonus marks by explaining why that approach should give a similar answer).